# How can i retrieve data from plist

Tags: ios, nsarray, plist, nsdictionary

hi i have a plist of the following format [image]

I want to sort those books according to their categories id. I have an array "TotalCategory" with all category id's (eg:cat1,cat2..) ,I want to open the below plist and check with each book and its category id whether its matching or not.If the category id i have is matching with a category id of given book then then i want to add that category id and book id(bid) to a new dictionary .Is it possible??

```
NSDictionary *booksPlist = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
NSArray *categoryId=[[booksPlist objectForKey:@"catlist"]valueForKey:@"cid"];
NSLog(@"%@",categoryId);

// getting category list

NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *allBooksPath = [[paths objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Allbooks.plist"];
NSDictionary *allBookPlist=[[NSDictionary alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:allBooksPath];

NSArray *bookid=[[allBookPlist objectForKey:@"listbook"]valueForKey:@"bid"];
NSString *s=[[[allBookPlist objectForKey:@"listbook"]objectForKey:@"cate" ]valueForKey:@"categories"];  //// this line shows exception


 NSLog(@"%@",s);
```

///   I WANT THIS :::
I want to check the category id with me and category id's inside each book if its matching then retrieve that book id (bid) thats it

Comment: This is not an Xcode question.

Comment: iam doing this using xcode

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/PropertyLists/SerializePlist/SerializePlist.html Is that helpful?

Comment: @adaam :appreciate ur help,but i need a code ,please

Comment: @Naveen I know, but this is still not an Xcode question.

Comment: @H2CO3 do u knw the answer ?or not?

Comment: @Naveen I do, I'm just curious if you have any code to show us (i. e. what have you tried? All is clearly in the documentation.)

Comment: check the updated codes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not very clear to what your request is, but I see several problems with your code.

First of all, don't confuse the `-objectForKey:` method of `NSDictionary` with the `valueForKey:` method of the informal protocol `NSKeyValueCoding`.

The latter is used for `KVC` access and it's better not to mix them without knowing it. It may work, but it may also explode under some circumstances.
Stick with `objectForKey:` or better you can use the modern subscribed syntax

```
[dict objectForKey:@"whatever"];
```

is equivalent to

```
dict[@"whatever"];
```

---

That said, let's face your specific problem.
First of all `listbook` is an array, so you cannot do

```
[[allBookPlist objectForKey:@"listbook"]valueForKey:@"bid"];
```

You need to access to an array element first, so in modern syntax you should do

```
NSString * bookId = allBookPlist[@"listbook"][0][@"bid"];
```

to get the `bid` of the first element. If you want to collect them, just iterate on the array

```
NSArray * books = allBookPlist[@"listbook"];
NSMutableArray * bookIds = [@[] mutableCopy]
for (NSDictionary * book in books) {
     [bookIds addObject:book[@"bid"]];
}
```

A similar approach can be used for getting the categories from each book.

Comment: this is a Q&A website, not a we-do-the-work-for-you website. Tell what's your doubt and somebody will answer.